# how to press keyboard with Jquery/ Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, eventtrigger

I am new to development, I wanna know is there method to call/trigger key event using any frontend programs.

Comment: Client-side javascript cannot control the browser in this way. This is a security issue.

Comment: If you want fullscreen, ask for that (or search for questions asking that; it's been asked before), don't bother with the very roundabout fact that a non-javascript solution would be to press a certain key on the keyboard.

Comment: I don't think that can't be done. Do check the answers that have already been asked before. Cheers.

Comment: Actually, I want it for another purpose my aim here is to access keyboard

Comment: why you are giving down voting, I am asking for suggestions to access a keyboard. @All down voters

Answer (score 1):

You can full screen the browser directly using below code

```
var docElement, request;

    docElement = document.documentElement;
    request = docElement.requestFullScreen || docElement.webkitRequestFullScreen || 
                  docElement.mozRequestFullScreen || docElement.msRequestFullScreen;

    if(typeof request!="undefined" && request){
        request.call(docElement);
    }
```

Answer (score -3):

//These method use to request full screen

```
var docElm = document.documentElement;
if (docElm.requestFullscreen) {
    docElm.requestFullscreen();
}
else if (docElm.mozRequestFullScreen) {
    docElm.mozRequestFullScreen();
}
else if (docElm.webkitRequestFullScreen) {
    docElm.webkitRequestFullScreen();
}
```

//Exit the full screen

```
if (document.exitFullscreen) {
    document.exitFullscreen();
}
else if (document.mozCancelFullScreen) {
    document.mozCancelFullScreen();
}
else if (document.webkitCancelFullScreen) {
    document.webkitCancelFullScreen();
}
```

Other way using  Screenfull.js
http://www.paulund.co.uk/javascript-full-screen-api

Comment: this should be a commment